# Will many social media webpages hurt my ranking?

Tags: seo, google, ranking

I have an old website and I'm working on a new website section dedicated to fun and very short news, sometimes with pictures. Unlike my classic pages, I don't care about SEO trafic of this new section.
Nevertheless I'm afraid of what Google will 'think' of my website as a whole when in 6 months, 50% of my webpages will have poor text content.

Should I noindex my new pages? Should I robots.txt them? Should I trash them after a few weeks? Should I put them into a dedicated subdomain? A friend of mine told to not link to them?

Internet people, please help

Answer (score 2):

I would let Google index them anyway- at least for a while. Get your new traffic going. If later you feel that you have too many thin pages, then you can noindex the thin ones if it is not too hard. I would not use any other method.

*You may be surprised.*

Your new pages may not be so thin afterall. Often, these shorter pages will inspire you to create and in doing so, some pages may be just what the doctor ordered. Do not be afraid to put yourself into your work even if you think it is silly stuff. Silly is good. But sometimes silly is serious. Roll with it and see what happens. You may be pleasantly surprised. Proud too.

Comment: +1 For  **Silly is good. But sometimes silly is serious**

Answer (score 0):

If the content is poor quality, then your concern is valid. However consider if the content really is poor quality.

**Consider Content Quality:**

1. Is it original content or copied?
2. Would someone who stumbled on it find it interesting and possibly link to it or repost?
3. Does it provide value to users?
4. Does it fit in with the main purpose of your main website?

If it truly is poor quality content, then find a way to decouple it from the main pages by using a different domain name. It could hurt your main site if its totally unrelated and lacks value to your main user base.

Answer (score 0):

You need not worry much about what Google will think as long as your website users are enjoying with your pages. Poor text content is not bad as long as you are genuinely posting stuff that visitors coming to your website want at the first place.

Let Google index these pages and then you try to analyze how your website visitors are responding to these pages and then act accordingly.